# My Flutter app doesnt appear in the emulator when I try to run it

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, dart

I am trying to run my application and show it in the emulator, but this is what only apears on the emulator. shown in this image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpVF7.png)

```
this is the logs in the debug console




      Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
Parameter format not correct -
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Connecting to VM Service at ws://127.0.0.1:59401/3lHsVpO1fSY=/ws
W/om.grabbitv.ap( 9255): Verification of void com.google.android.gms.tasks.TaskCompletionSource.<init>() took 151.020ms (72.84 bytecodes/s) (1496B approximate peak alloc)
[GETX] Instance "PrefUtils" has been created
[GETX] Instance "ApiClient" has been created
[GETX] Instance "ApiClient" has been initialized
[GETX] Instance "NetworkInfo" has been created
[GETX] Instance "GetMaterialController" has been created
[GETX] Instance "GetMaterialController" has been initialized
[GETX] GOING TO ROUTE /initialRoute
[GETX] Instance "WelcomeController" has been created
[GETX] Instance "WelcomeController" has been initialized
I/FirebaseApp( 9255): Device unlocked: initializing all Firebase APIs for app [DEFAULT]
W/om.grabbitv.ap( 9255): Suspending all threads took: 18.143ms
[GETX] REPLACE ROUTE /initialRoute
[GETX] NEW ROUTE /login_screen
```

Comment: debug console shows some exception.
Can you please share the whole detail debug console

Comment: what do you mean? thats the whole already

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

It shows exception.
Can you please share this exception. Thats is display in image as i mentioned below.

[image]